# Magento 2.1.6 - MercadoPago

Tags: mercadopago, magento2

Estoy instalando para un ecommerce Magento 2.1.6 Community Edition.

Me falta la pata de MercadoPago, tengo acceso root por ssh sin problemas, subí el contenido de scr/MercadoPago en la carpeta raíz del magento (a la misma altura que "app", "pub", etc), pero cuando ejecuto los comandos para habilitarlo me dice que no existe.

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método recomendado para instalar módulos en Magento 2 es por medio de composer, en caso que la extensión ofrezca dicha opción.

Según la documentación de MercadoPago, agregas el repositorio a tu composer.json:

```
"repositories": [ { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/mercadopago/cart-magento2" } ]
```

Posteriormente descargas el paquete de la extensión:

```
composer require mercadopago/magento2-plugin
```

Más información: https://github.com/mercadopago/cart-magento2

---

Estuve revisando la documentación y parece haber un error en la forma como plantean la instalación manual, el contenido de `src/MercadoPago` debería ser copiado a `app/code/MercadoPago`.

Comment: Esta perfecto, ahí funciono.